# Vector Sort JAVA

Tags: java, sorting, vector

I have created a Vector object to store data in `Table` object as `Vector<Table>`. `Vector<Table>` contains components as below.

```
[Vector<Record> records, String tableName, String keyColumnName, int recordCount, int columnCount]
```

I need to sort `tableName` in above Vector to my own order and return `Vector<Table>` with `sorted tableNames` for other processes.

How could i do this ?

**UPDATED**

I have wrote method as below.

```
private Vector<Table> orderTables(Vector<Table> loadTables) {

    ArrayList<String> tableNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (Table table : loadTables) {

        String tblName = table.getTableName();
        tableNames.add(tblName);

    }
    Collections.sort(tableNames, new MyComparable());

    return null;
}
```

But i have no idea about how to write `Comparator` to this. My own sort order is stored in `.properties` file. i can read it and get value. but i have no idea about how to compare it.

How could i do it ?

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you use `Collections.sort` with your own, custom, `Comparator`.

Comment: And yet another recommendation: avoid using `Vector`. Use any other `List` implementation (`ArrayList`, `LinkedList` etc.) for your choice.

Comment: @AlexR , @aioobe  : i have updated my question. i have no idea about how to write `Comparator`. i studied some examples i found from google search. but i'm unable to write a `Comparator` for my necessity.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to give a pseudocode

```
TableComparator implements Comparator{
   int compare(Table source, Table destination){
     //implement your own custom logic of comparison
   }
}

Vector<Table> vectorTable = new Vector<Table>();
TableComparator tableComparator = new TableComparator();
```

Now use this comparator in `Collections.sort(vectorTable,tableComparator);`

Comment: @ raddykrish : cant use Vector in `Collections.sort()`. it should be `Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`

Comment: Vector also implements List. Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html